# Imagemagick background gradient

Tags: php, imagemagick

I've got some basic code working to generate an image with a solid background. However I was wondering how I can make a gradient. This is my code:

```
<?php
function process($inputdata)
{
/* Create some objects */
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'gray' );

/* New image */
$image->newImage(400, 300, $pixel);

/* Black text */
$draw->setFillColor('black');

/* Font properties */
$draw->setFont('Bookman-DemiItalic');
$draw->setFontSize( 30 );

/* Create text */
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, $inputdata);

/* Give image a format */
$image->setImageFormat('png');

/* Output the image with headers */
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
return;
}
```

The closest code I could find is something like this:

```
$gradient = new Imagick();
$gradient->newPseudoImage(400, 300, 'gradient:blue-red');
```

But I don't know how I then combine the gradient with the text.

Comment: https://www.osd.net/blog/web-development/php/generate-gradient-image-with-php/

Comment: @clearshot66 I think that's for GD not imagemagick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `compositeImage` function. It combine one image into another. Create one Imagick instance with gradient, second one with text and alpha channel background, and combine them into the one.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php

```
$text = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
$width = 1000;
$height = 1000;

$textBackground = new ImagickPixel('transparent');
$textColor = new ImagickPixel('#000');

$gradient = new Imagick();
$gradient->newPseudoImage($width, $height, 'gradient:blue-red');

$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage($width, $height, $textBackground);

$gradient->setImageColorspace($image->getImageColorspace());

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor($textColor);
$draw->setFontSize( 10 );

$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, $text);

$gradient->compositeImage($image, Imagick::COMPOSITE_MATHEMATICS, 0, 0);
$gradient->setImageFormat('png');

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code - am I right in saying this is how it should look in full, I feel like I have my made a mistake putting your code in because it doesn't work? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b5cb6fed5d3bdc017b2e3888a212bcd8

Comment: I've run this part of code, and it didn't work as expected. The reason was missing line `$gradient->setImageColorspace($image->getImageColorspace());` (pseudo image should have set colorspace). I've updated the answer.